# Smarty Zend variable source

Tags: php, zend-framework, smarty

Is there a way to trace in which controller function the Smarty variables are assigned in Zend framework?

Example below:

```
{$TITLE}
```

This is in search.tpl

This must have been assigned using Smarty's assign function.

How can I locate that assignment?

Answer (score 0):

Since the `assign` (documentation [here](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/api.assign.tpl)) function takes only 2 parameters, which are the `key` and the `value` (or a single parameter of `key` / `value` pairs) you probably won't be able to find programmatically what is the source of the assignation.

A Smarty template can also assign a value, using `{assign}` (documentation [here](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.assign.tpl)).

What you can do though, is a `Find in Files` (depending on your IDE, all decent ones like Sublime Text 2, Visual Studio, Notepad++, etc... offer you a way to look for a string in all the files in a folder, often giving you more options like filtering on the extension of the file) for the string `->assign("Title"` or simply the literal `"title"` if you believe a template could have assigned it. From there, you will be able to find which source files assign this value. If there are multiple places where it's set and you want to debug which one gets executed, I'd suggest using some `echo` calls, they will appear in your HTML document right before your `Template`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried echo but it doesn't seem to echo out from the controller. The variables are accessible only via assign menthod. Is there a reason why?

Comment: @JohnKim Are you sure your controller is assigning Title?

Comment: The tpl file is calling [[$TITLE]] and I'm not sure where this is coming from and it's definitely not assigned inside Smarty template itself

Comment: You mean {$TITLE}? a .tpl can use {assign} [doc](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.assign.tpl)... a find in files using "title" through all your files should give you places where this literal is used, and you should be able to find the source of the value!